# Not Sure Why My CSS Background For My Hero Section Isn't Showing Up

Tags: html, css

Completely new to HTML/CSS, I'm struggling to find the answer as to why my Background Image isn't showing up.

My folder structure goes as follows:
.../Images/Hero/hero-background.jpg

This 'Images' folder is in the same directory as my index.html.

My index.html:

```
        <div class="hero">
            <div class="container">

                <p class="subheading">Whether You Need It For Work Or Gaming...</p>

                    <h1>Learn How To Build An EPIC Battlestation Setup</h1>

                    <a href="#" class="main-hero-cta">Buying Guides</a>
                    <a href="#" class="secondary-hero-cta">Info Guides</a>

            </div>
        </div>
```

My CSS:

```
// Hero Section Start

.hero {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70vh;
    background: url("...Images/Hero/hero-background.svg");

    .subheading {
        font-family: 'Poppins';
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 0.8em;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: gray;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 2.5em;
        line-height: 1.3em;
        margin: 0.5em;
        padding: 0 15em;
    }
}
```

I have tried also tried:

- Adding display: block;
- Trying an .svg
- Putting it in the container class

Nothing has worked, could there be something that is on top of the background that is blocking it from showing?

Help is much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: change background url: ../Images/Hero/hero-background.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use ../ to go out of a folder. So try this:

background: url("../Images/Hero/hero-background.svg");

And Check your file path ;)

Comment: Hey Azubi,

Thanks for that. I'm a dumbass, realized I need to put the Hero folder in my CSS folder.

I have my folder structure like:
.../Desktop/redesign-2021/css
.../Desktop/redesign-2021/Images/Hero/hero-background.jpg

Oh, and I tested your one too, That worked as well. I was doing:
URL("...Images/Hero/hero-background.svg") instead of:
(".../Images/Hero/hero-background.svg").

That works better :)